# Initialize a string in a stored function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I call this procedure without any problem :

```
SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable('current_user_id')::INT ;
```

If I call it inside another stored procedure like this :

```
-- Get current User Id --
SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable('current_user_id')::INT INTO __currentUserId ;
```

I have this error :

```
ERROR : Syntax error near "current_user_id"
LINE 25:   SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable('current_user_id')::INT INTO _...
```

It is probably a stupid syntax error... If someone can help a poor MySQL user starting using PG !

EDIT 1 :

```
SELECT version();
PostgreSQL 9.3.3 on i686-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc-4.4.real (Debian 4.4.5-8) 4.4.5, 32-bit
```

This is the result of the version() call.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_getGlobalVariable (__variableName VARCHAR(64))
RETURNS VARCHAR
AS
' 
DECLARE

BEGIN

    RETURN  (SELECT value FROM tmp_variables
            WHERE name = __variableName) ;

END ;
'
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

The procedure to get the global variable in the temporary table.*

EDIT 2 :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_insertSite (__siteName VARCHAR(70), __siteDescription  TEXT, __siteLatitude NUMERIC, __siteLongitude NUMERIC)
RETURNS INT
AS
' 
DECLARE

-- Variables
__right_edge_father INT ;
__left_edge_father INT ;
__depth_father INT ;
__nbrSites INT ;
__insertId INT ;
__currentUserId INT ;

BEGIN

    -- Check if tree is empty --
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO __nbrSites
    FROM site ;

    -- Get current User Id --
    SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable('current_user_id')::INT INTO __currentUserId ;

    IF __nbrSites = 0 THEN

        INSERT INTO site (site_name, site_description, site_latitude, site_longitude, site_left_edge, site_right_edge, site_depth, site_create_dt, site_create_user_id)
        VALUES(__siteName, __siteDescription, 0.0, 0.0, 1, 2, 0, LOCALTIMESTAMP, __currentUserId)
        RETURNING site_id INTO __insertId;

    ELSE

        -- Get father edges --
        SELECT site_left_edge, site_right_edge, site_depth
        INTO __left_edge_father, __right_edge_father, __depth_father
        FROM site
        WHERE site_id = (SELECT site_id FROM site WHERE site_depth = 0 LIMIT 1) ;

        -- Updates left edges --
        UPDATE site
        SET site_left_edge = site_left_edge + 2
        WHERE site_left_edge >= __right_edge_father ;

        -- Updates right edges --
        UPDATE site
        SET site_right_edge = site_right_edge + 2
        WHERE site_right_edge >= __right_edge_father ;

        -- Insert new node --
        INSERT INTO site (site_name, site_description, site_latitude, site_longitude, site_left_edge, site_right_edge, site_depth, site_create_dt, site_create_user_id)
        VALUES(__siteName, __siteDescription, __siteLatitude, __siteLongitude, __right_edge_father, __right_edge_father+1, __depth_father+1, LOCALTIMESTAMP, __currentUserId)
        RETURNING site_id INTO __insertId;

    END IF ;

    RETURN __insertId ;

END ;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: What PostgreSQL version is this? And what language is the procedure in? (Show the full procedure definition and output of `SELECT version()` if possible). Edit your question and comment here when done.

Comment: Unrelated but: don't put the language name in single quotes. It's an identifier, not a string constant.

Comment: Thanks. You haven't actually shown the procedure that has the error, though. You've shown the one that you are calling, the one that works.

Comment: I have the solution... The problem is the stupid choice of delimiters for the body of the procedure !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are using single quotes to encapsulate the function body, and so, when you try to add single quotes inside the body, you need to escape it, for instance:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_insertSite (...)
RETURNS INT
AS
' 
DECLARE
...
    -- Get current User Id --
    SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable(''current_user_id'')::INT INTO __currentUserId ;
...
    RETURN __insertId ;

END ;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

That would work nice. But I recommend you to use [dollar-quoting](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) and so you don't have to worry with single-quote escaping inside the function body, as the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION SP_insertSite (...)
RETURNS INT
AS
$$
DECLARE
...
    -- Get current User Id --
    SELECT SP_getGlobalVariable('current_user_id')::INT INTO __currentUserId ;
...
    RETURN __insertId ;

END ;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

I'd recommend you to read [PostgreSQL docs about the usage of dollar-quoting in PL/pgSQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-DOLLAR-QUOTING) (the entire document, not just this sub-section is also interesting to read).

Comment: Thanks Matheus, I've seen this (last comment of the first post).

Comment: @GuilhemG., sorry, I haven't seem it. Anyway I think it is good to left a proper solution to the topic. :)